# Go to chat message with specific text with Telegram API

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm looking for information about this, but I don't find anything.

Is possible send to user to a chat message that contains a specific text?

Answer (score 0):

This request below can be made with multiple languages.

https://api.telegram.org/bot[BOT_API_KEY]/sendMessage?chat_id=[MY_CHANNEL_NAME]&text=[MY_MESSAGE_TEXT]

where:

BOT_API_KEY is the API Key when you created your bot

MY_CHANNEL_NAME is the handle of your channel (e.g. @my_channel_name)

MY_MESSAGE_TEXT is the message you want to send (URL-encoded)

https://medium.com/@xabaras/sending-a-message-to-a-telegram-channel-the-easy-way-eb0a0b32968